# API key to fetch data

Tags: api, api-key

I have API key, testuserid and testChargingid. I do not know the baseURL. How can I fetch data from API using api key? I am looking for some ideas as I am new to this fetching data from API. Programming language can be either python or C#.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. To access an API you have to know it's URL, just like a website. You use the key as a means of authentication, this key can be put inside the query string or inside the header of your request.
I suggest you do further research how you should call API's, maybe watch some video's about this topic. This is pretty basic knowledge.